# PHPUnit does not show fatal error

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit

I invoke phpunit for index action of index controller in My project.I am using BVB grid in index action for records display. Some how I want to check if phpunit is worked while php fatal error occured.So I changed variable name for  testing. In browser  I got error but in phpunit testcase is passed for that action.Is  there any issue?

Comment: What does your test look like?  Are you asserting anything on the response?  The fact that your test doesn't fail is an issue.

Comment: I got asserting 0 if there is error but can't doesn't get error message in json log of phpunit.If there is no error then it show asserting 1.You can understand from this that there is something wrong but what is actual problem u can't get.

Comment: The response object in your test contains the error message that you see in the browser. So the fact that your test passes in this case means that you are not asserting anything about what is to be displayed. Add an assertion for what is supposed to be displayed when the action works. What text do you want to see if the action worked properly. That is likely the problem but workout seeing the actual test I can't be more specific.